# Query regarding installing wireless WiFi in ubuntu17.10

Tags: drivers, wireless

Is there anybody who can help me?

I recently had installed Ubuntu 17.10 and it is not showing WiFi icon(wireless), through which I want to connect my laptop.

It is a newly bought HP 15 BS576.

But still whenever I connect my hot-spot with USB, ethernet is connected, but I want to connect internet as wireless hotspot.

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lsmod | grep cfg80211`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the icon just to the right of the battery indicator on the top right corner of the screen.  It has wifi options, log out, power off, and others.  Something new to get used to

Comment: sorry! I am using ubuntu 17.10 and it is not showing wifi icon.

Comment: It doesn't show a wifi icon but there is a menu button